# How do I properly save a file from chromedriver in a docker container with django?

Tags: python, django, selenium

I'm doing Django + Chrome standalone selenium, I can't configure the download folder correctly. I've been trying to do it for half a day, I've never been able to solve the problem like that.
Tell me how to do it right?

I need chrome to save files to a folder from the django project, namely in app/media/uploads

I tried to do this:

```
chrome:
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
        container_name: Chrome-selenium
        ports:
            - "4444:4444"
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app
            - media:/app/media
        privileged: true
        shm_size: 2g
        restart: always
```

And at the very start with the command:

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = True
    # User Agent
    options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36 Edg/92.0.902.84')
    # Disable driver mode
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    
    # Download settings
    download_dir = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'uploads') ??

    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {   
        'download.default_directory': download_dir,
        'download.prompt_for_download': False,
        'download.directory_upgrade': True,
        'safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled': False,
        'safebrowsing.enabled': False
    })
     
    driver = webdriver.Remote("http://chrome:4444/wd/hub", options=options)
```

But after launching from django, no file is saved, more precisely, I do not know where it is saved, but definitely not where I indicated

Comment: Django only uploads files in the root directory. you can mount a volume in Django upload directory

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work at all, it looks like I caught some kind of glitch in the Windows system.
But, found a solution, I just went from standalone to a simple installation of chromium chromium-drvier. Everything works as it should right away!